# How to Pass Username and Password using POSTMAN - Rest Client?

Tags: postman

I am a new bee in using [POSTMAN - Rest Client - Chrome API](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)

I want to use the `Basic Auth` which is available in POSTMAN.

I am trying to login into my Google account at `url` - "https://www.gmail.com".

I provided my `Username & Password` in the `Basic Auth` and I had tried `GET and POST`.

I got a `Status 200 OK` which loads me the `home page` but it is not logged in.

*I know that i need to change the url, but i am not able to find the correct one which to use?*

It would be helpful if @examples are provided for the Different Types of Auth Provided as well.

Comment: Hello, I am also interested in learning how to use this tool, I found that basic oauth is deprecated for Google APIs, so you might need to use oauth 2.0. This is a link with explanation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 , first you need to get some api keys from google, then get the url where you are gonna send those keys to get an access token... and follow the process. (I am still reading this doc, I am keen to learn this stuff).

Comment: Gmail is not using basic auth, you rather use Oauth2 ;)

Answer (score 2):

The link you have provided is deprecated. I don't know if the Gmail API allowed Basic Auth at the time you asked the question, but right now it needs OAuth 2.0, as indicated in the opening lines [here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server).

The correct url is `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth`, and [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#formingtheurl) explains how to supply the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Google stopped allowing http clients(like Postman) accessing its APIs through Basic Auth one year back or more. Now, Google allowing its APIs to be accessed using OAuth 2.0.

For accessing Google APIs, you need to setup an OAuth Application, [here](http://console.developer.google.com)
When you create this OAuth Application, Google will generate ClientId and ClientSecret.

With these clientId and clientSecret, you need to generate Access and Refresh Tokens and eventually, you will use these tokens to access Google APIs.
Read more about Google OAuth 2.0 and you will get more information about accessing APIs.